# Data Sheet help: Current flowing through a MOSFET module

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, powermosfet, module, power-modules

In a MOSFET module, when looking at the data sheet can I assume the current through each MOSFET device is the given Id, or is Id the current moving through the entire MOSFET module?

For the data sheet attached I'm assuming the current through each MOSFET is 265 A and through the module is 530 A?
Or is 530A going through each MOSFET under maximum operation?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image: Data sheet 2]

[image: Figure 20]

Comment: Single. Specs. Only. There may be a Pmax for entire package with sink.

Comment: As the package has a set of pins for each device, the specs are per device. This is confirmed by the note that the current limit is 30 A due to the press-fit pins. Bear in mind that's a maximum, not a recommended, operating current.

Comment: What does Fig. 20 show you?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson please find it added to the end

Answer (score 0):

> Or is 530A going through each MOSFET under maximum operation?

Yes. The specs are for an individual MOSFET in the module, not the module as a whole, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: Isn't 530A too high to be going though the MOSFET? I thought it would be

Comment: @FromMyWindow The manufacturer promises that under ideal conditions (the module somehow kept at 25 C) you can maintain a continous drain current as high as 719 A, and 541 A with the module at 90 C. In practice you want a healthy margin much lower than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! (I'll assume that's the case with modules which are full bridge)